# UILabel Highlighting Text

Tags: uilabel, highlighting

Can anyone quickly help me?  I've been playing with this for hours and don't understand why this isn't working?

I'm trying to update highlighted text in a selected label (which is referenced in an array of UILabels previously defined).

This method is called by a receiving IBAction from a UISlider in the view interface.

However, when I retrieve the selected UILabel object from the array and set its HIGHLIGHTED property, there's no corresponding reaction on the view interface.  I'm under the impression that its supposed to automatically redraw the view with text highlighted using the code below.

PS: My connections seem to all be correct the Interface Builder (i.e., IBOutlet UILabels are properly mapped/connected and the UISlider which triggers this method is connected through IBAction).

Am I missing something?

```
- (IBAction) changeHighlightedLabel: (id)sender
{

// Setup
UILabel *selectedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
selectedLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];

// Interpret slider value and round to integer
UISlider *temp = sender;
float unroundedTempValue = [temp value];
float roundedTempValue = roundf(unroundedTempValue);

// Select the UILabel object from the UI Label array based on slider valuer
selectedLabel = [uiLabelArray objectAtIndex:roundedTempValue];

// Highlight the selected label
selectedLabel.highlighted = YES;

}
```

I've also tried substituting...

```
    selectedCountryLabel = [[uiCountryLabelArray objectAtIndex:roundedTempValue] isHighlighted];
```

... for the last line.  Still doesn't work.

Any feedback or help please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a `UILabel` and setting `highlightedTextColor` property to that first and then you are overwriting that with a `UILabel` from array. Since you are not setting any `highlightedTextColor` this time, the `highlighted` property will not work on label.

Change it as follows.

```
- (IBAction) changeHighlightedLabel: (id)sender
{

   // Interpret slider value and round to integer
   UISlider *temp = sender;
   float unroundedTempValue = [temp value];
   float roundedTempValue = roundf(unroundedTempValue);

   // Select the UILabel object from the UI Label array based on slider valuer
   selectedLabel = [uiLabelArray objectAtIndex:roundedTempValue];

   // Highlight the selected label
   selectedLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   selectedLabel.highlighted = YES;
}
```